# How can you use submodules with git-managed dotfiles?

Tags: git, git-submodules, dotfiles

I use a git repository to manage my dotfiles, and I'm having the hardest time getting submodules to work right (most of my .vim has a lot of external plugins)

I have an alias cgit to do (not sure if it's relevant)
    alias cgit='GIT_DIR=/home/myuser/.config-git GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/myuser/. git'"

So, I can pull the repository with cgit pull, but I can't get submodules to checkout/update:

```
$ cgit submodule status
-9895285042a2fd5691b2f6582aa979e4d1bdffea .vim/bundle/ack
-e9267044261481fbb6717b482c2f3811eb61b409 .vim/bundle/command-t
<snip>
$ cgit submodule init
$ cgit submodule update
fatal: working tree '/home/myuser/.' already exists.
Clone of 'https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim.git' into submodule path '.vim/bundle/ack' failed
$
```

I've tried removing that specific directory and trying again, and it just bombs. My .gitmodules doesn't have /home/myuser/. and my .config-git/config doesn't have any references to my home directory either, so I'm at a loss. If it helps, my version of git is 1.7.4.1

thanks!

**UPDATE**

It appears that first thing was a weird bug where git submodule wasn't accepting the environment variables (though other git commands were), but it required the command line arg be passed. Now, the clone works, it just complains (I fixed the ack config manually)

```
Cloning into '.vim/bundle/command-t'...
remote: Counting objects: 2659, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1089/1089), done.
remote: Total 2659 (delta 1453), reused 2524 (delta 1325)
Receiving objects: 100% (2659/2659), 447.42 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1453/1453), done.
fatal: Could not chdir to '../../../../../../../nfs_mounts/home/myuser/.vim/bundle/command-t': No such file or directory
```

And if I look in ~/.config-git/modules/.vim/ack/config, I see:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    worktree = ../../../../../../../nfs_mounts/home/myuser/.vim/bundle/command-t
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://github.com/wincent/Command-T.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

but if I 'ls' that worktree, it appears to be there. If I remove all the ../ , then try the git again it appears to work

Comment: Have you changed your `cgit` alias now?  Or any other part of the process?  That's not a bug in `git` the problem was that the submodules commands _were_ getting the overriden `GIT_DIR`  By using the command line options you stopped overriding things for the submodules.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you have `GIT_DIR` set.  It looks like the submodule clone is trying to put the `.git` directory for the submodule in `~/.git` but your home git directory is already there.

What's the purpose of setting GIT_DIR like that?

Comment: because I didn't want regular git commands to end up searching for/finding the dotfiles git repository. I wonder if there's a reason git submodule isn't accepting GIT_DIR...

Comment: I think that it is, normally it would put the `.git` directory inside the submodule clone.  It looks like your submodule `GIT_DIR` is the same as your home directory `GIT_DIR` because both have been overridden.  Try `[--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>]`, I don't think you want to override the submodule values which _I think_ is what's happening.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do it. This seems like a bug, if it's actually doing this

Comment: GIT_DIR=/home/myuser/.config-git GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/myuser/. git  --git-dir=/home/myuser/.config-git --work-tree=/home/myuser submodule update --init
fatal: working tree '/home/myuser' already exists.
Clone of 'https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim.git' into submodule path '.vim/bundle/ack' failed

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific.  Remove the `GIT_DIR= GIT_WORK_TREE=` and replace them with the command line options.

Comment: Huh, that worked to clone, but now it's just setting worktree wrong, I'm gonna update the question